# How to add items to the watchlist in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I Am trying to figure out how can I add the items to watchlist,

The steps am trying to carry out here are, when a user clicks on add button, the items should be added to the watchlist page/component which I have created.

Please see the hierarchy of the component.
I would like to show added items on the watchlist page.

[image]

Please see the code I tried.

```
const [watchlist, setWatchlist] = useState ([]);

const handleWatchlist = (movieData) => {
   const newList = [...watchlist, movieData]
   setWatchlist(newList)
   console.log(newList)
}




<Button className = {classes.cardButton}size = "small" onClick = {  ()=> handleWatchlist(movie) }> Add </Button>
```

When I try to inspect, the result is,  it shows the items are added but can not pass on to the watchlist component? How can use a prop to pass this value and show them?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks a million

Comment: Can you please provide your code in a code sandbox?

Comment: Can you provide the full code

Comment: Hi @AmilaSenadheera  Please find the link of the full code below Thanks for your help https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products/Products.jsx

Comment: Hi @JibinFrancis  Please find the link of the full code below Thanks for your help https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products/Products.jsx

Comment: Hi All , Also I have updated the code which is somewhat giving a 1% result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, but I figured out the solution by using two approaches and they are

Which is **props drilling, i.e. is to perform the useState action** in my App.js which is my main page where I have product and watchlist component.

This is the best way I would suggest other people use as well is by using **the contextAPI and useContext hooks**. A simple and easy way to pass any data anywhere in the app.

Please see the full code with the working solution below on the codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products

The working app, where I can add the products to the watchlist.

[working demo app](https://m2mtn.csb.app/products)

Answer (score 1):

The `Button` doesn't pass any argument in `handleWatchlist` in your example. I don't know how `Button` component looks like, but passing the arg could look like the example below:

```js
const Button = ({ onClick }) => {

  const value = "some value";

  return <button onClick={() => onClick(value)}>Button</button>;
};

const WatchList = () => {
...
return <Button onClick={handleWatchlist}>Add</Button>
```

Comment: Hi @JacekTessen I have updated the code and tried a away you said by search for the result, however I have got !% output but seems like not able to pass the data and use it on the other component. Please see the link for source code. Thanks https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/components/Products/Products.jsx